# How to I select distinct records with ids from a database in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, distinct

I am trying to select distinct records to populate a select tag and I need the ids from the query but when I write a query like this:

```
Topic.select(:name).distinct
```

It comes back with results that look like this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Topic id: nil, name: "Ruby">, #<Topic id: nil, name: "Python">, #<Topic id: nil, name: "tingz">, #<Topic id: nil, name: "Javascript">, #<Topic id: nil, name: "Java">]>
```

And in order to get my select drop down to work properly I need the corresponding ids to be returned as well

This is the select tag that I am using in my view:

```
<%= select_tag :topic_search, options_from_collection_for_select(Topic.select(:name).distinct, :id, :name), placeholder: "Select topic" %>
```

Does anyone have any idea of what the best way of doing something like this is?

Comment: What version of Rails are you on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
Topic.select('distinct on(name) id, name').order(:name)
```

Comment: What is `on` in distinct? Never seen and didn't work with `sqlite3`.

Comment: @maniek Cool answer, I answered this question myself but I like your answer more!

Comment: @KirtiThorat It's a Postgresql-ism . Basically, take the first id for a given name. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 4.x, use

```
Topic.select(:id, :name).distinct
```

**NOTE:**

To answer your question in comment i.e.,

> Nope that still returns repeat values if the same name was entered
>   twice

You cannot do that. Suppose you have Python in two records then they'll have two different ids(as its primary key). Which id will you map in that case for the distinct Python

Comment: @Kirti Thorat Nope that still returns repeat values if the same name was entered twice

Comment: You cannot do that. Suppose you have `Python` in two records then they'll have two `different ids(as its primary key)`. Which id will you map in that case for the distinct `Python`?

Comment: @vee Any thoughts on my above comment.

Comment: @KirtiThorat, sure, I would have used Jack and Jill in the example :)  I would suggest mentioning "In rails 4" as the syntax does not work in Rails 3, and there is still a huge Rails 3 user group.

Comment: @vee Thanks for confirming :) Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that one way to get around this issue is to not use the Rails helper of:

```
options_from_collection_for_select
```

and instead use:

```
options_for_select
```

and pass in a query statement that looks like this into options_for_select:

```
<%= select_tag :topic_search, options_for_select(Topic.uniq.pluck(:name)), prompt: "Select topic" %>
```

This way you pass in an array and don't have to worry about obtaining unique id's